# Xamarin forms Android timeout issue on StartUp

Tags: xamarin.android, timeout, xamarin.forms, startup, uitest

**Hi, my android application sometimes stucks on startup. On Xamarin test cloud the failure seems like;**

SetUp : System.TimeoutException : Timed out waiting...
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.WaitForHelper.WaitFor (System.Func`1 predicate, System.String timeoutMessage, Nullable`1 timeout, Nullable`1 retryFrequency, Nullable`1 postTimeout) <0x7e4c998 + 0x004db> in :0
at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor (IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration) <0x7cacab8 + 0x0073b> in :0
at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp (AppDataMode appDataMode) <0x7cac008 + 0x00063> in :0
at YH.MB.Test.AppInitializer.StartApp (Platform platform) <0x7cab060 + 0x00027> in :0
at YH.MB.Test.Tests.BeforeEachTest () <0x7cab010 + 0x00013> in :0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x3249110 + 0x00093> in :0

**When i tried it on Samsung s3(on xamarin test cloud) there was a StackTrace too;**

java.lang.NullPointerException: key == null

at android.util.LruCache.get(LruCache.java: 113)
at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider$SettingsCache.isRedundantSetValue(SettingsProvider.java: 872)
at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.insert(SettingsProvider.java: 574)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java: 201)
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java: 148)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java: 367)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method: )

**I can not repeat that issue on debug mode. What can it be?**

My Android OnCreate method is;

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            // set the layout resources first
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            #if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ViewInitializedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.View.AutomationId))
                    {
                        e.NativeView.ContentDescription = e.View.AutomationId;
                    }
                };
            #endif

            var container = new SimpleContainer();

            container.Register<IDevice>(t => AndroidDevice.CurrentDevice);
            container.Register<IDisplay>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Display);
            container.Register<IMediaPicker>(t => new MediaPicker());
            container.Register<IFontManager>(t => new FontManager(t.Resolve<IDisplay>()));
            container.Register<INetwork>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Network);
            container.Register<IJsonSerializer, MBJsonSerializer>();
            container.Register<IPhoneService, PhoneService>();
            container.Register<IUserDialogs>(t => UserDialogs.Instance);

            if (!Resolver.IsSet)
                Resolver.SetResolver(container.GetResolver());

            UserDialogs.Init(this);

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

My UITest SetUp Method ;

```
 [TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
    [TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
    public class Tests
    {
        IApp app;
        Platform platform;


        public Tests(Platform platform)
        {
            this.platform = platform;

        }

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest()
        {
            app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code on what you are doing in the `[Setup]` method in your UI Tests and your `OnCreate` method in Android MainActivity? It would be helpful to see those specifics. Also maybe a Gist of the Device Log would be really helpful.

Comment: I have added my methods.I hope they can help.

Comment: Why are you using the `Forms.View.Initialized` event handler? You shouldn't need to use this anymore as the `AutomationId` should translate to the `Label` property that is covered with `Marked()`. I would try removing that. If the Id properties are not populating properly, take a look at this [guide](https://github.com/michael-watson/forms-xtc-guide) I created with Xamarin.Forms elements in Xamarin Test Cloud. These errors can be difficult to track down but you could always get more information from device log. Can you make this 1 test run shareable and post here or message me it directly?

Comment: I have not Test Cloud problem.I tried for problem solve to test cloud. My problem is my android application sometimes stucks on startup.Thanks